# Counting rows in many to many tables

Tags: sql-server, count, aggregate

Please help me with the following situation:

In SQL Server 2008 I have a database with the tables:

- **Installations** (`id, name`) which is unique for a given system
- **Products** (`Id, name`) which are installed on a system

And because a system has more products and the same product can be installed on multiple machines there is `InstallationXProduct` table withe their ids.

Another table `Usages` (`usageid, productid, date` etc) is linked to a product to keep track of product usages.

I need a script to link `Installation`, `Products` and `Usage` count for each `Installation-Product` pair, e.g.

```
Installation 1 Product A    2
Installation 1 Product B    3
Installation 2 Product A    1
Installation 2 Product C    2
```

Thank you for any help

Later EDIT:

Tables:

- `Installation`: `InstallationID, InstallationName`
- `Product`: `ProductID, ProductName`
- `InstallationXProduct`: `InstallationID, ProductID`
- `Usage`: `UsageID, DateRecorded, ProductID`

Set up data:

```
Insert into Installation values(1,'A')
Insert into Installation values(2,'B')

Insert into Product values (1,'P1')
Insert into Product values (2,'P2')

Insert into InstallationXProduct values (1,1)
Insert into InstallationXProduct values (2,1)
Insert into InstallationXProduct values (1,2)
Insert into InstallationXProduct values (2,2)
Insert into Usage values(1,getdate(),1)
Insert into Usage values(2,getdate(),2)
Insert into Usage values(3,getdate(),1)
```

Query to select:

```
select I.InstallationID, P.ProductID, count(U.UsageID)
from Installation I 
join InstallationXProduct IXC on I.InstallationID = IXC.InstallationID
join Product P on P.ProductID = IXC.ProductID
join Usage U on U.ProductID = P.ProductID
group by I.InstallationId,P.ProductID
```

returns:

```
1   1   2
2   1   2
1   2   1
2   2   1
```

After reading this light version I think I understand why it is not possible to split the usages in products and installations, there is no way I can tell whether usage one was recorded on product 1 from installation 1 or 2.

Comment: That'0s exactly the core of your problem - the `Usage` is **only** connected to products via the `ProductID` - there's no link whatsover to `Installation`, so no amount of SQL magic will be able to split up those usages between the various installations .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to count the rows in `Usages`, then something like this might be of help:

```
SELECT
    InstallationName = i.Name,
    ProductName = p.Name,
    UsageCount = COUNT(u.*)
FROM
    dbo.Installations i 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.InstallationXProduct ixp ON i.InstallationId = i.Id
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Product p ON ixp.ProductId = p.Id
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Usages u ON u.ProductId = p.Id
GROUP BY
    i.Name, p.Name
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank for your answer. I tried the script working only with the IDs but I get duplicates like this(sorry I don't know how to format a comment): 527 91 18089 529 91 18089. So the problem is that I get the same count of usages for all the installations. 18089 is the total usage for product 91 but should be split between installations.

Comment: @Alex: you cannot format comments - that's why it's a really bad idea to put code or output samples into it. Try to **update** your question by editing it instead! What would be helpful is to see your actual query that you used.

Comment: @Alex: also, from what I understand from your original post, `Usages` is only linked to product - so how should a query be able to "split" up those usages between installations??? Can you give the **exact** table structures for those tables mentioned? (column names and **data types**, too, please)